# Does the use of Static Variables in C# hinder secure coding practices?

Tags: c#, static, secure-coding

I am new to C# programming and I am currently using many static variables in my code. Below is one example:

```
class Program
{
    public int I//Can be used to access the variable i anywhere from the code as it is public
    {
        get { return i; }
        set { i = value; }
    }

    static int i = 0; // A private static integer
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        i = 1;// The main function is changing this integer
    }

    void reset() { 
        i = 0;// another function is changing the value of integer i
    }
}

class otherclass 
{
    void otherreset()
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        program.I = 1;// another function in another class is changing the value of integer i(indirectly)   

    }

}
```

1. The static variable **i** is available to all the functions in that class.
2. Then there is **I** which shares **i** with every function in the code as it is public. - not sure if I should even be doing this.

I did find this thread about [using static variables in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795502/what-is-the-use-of-static-variable-in-c-when-to-use-it-why-cant-i-declare-th) but I'd like to know, if this is a standard practice from a security perspective. I am concerned that the variable resides in the same location in memory throughout the execution of the program.

Are there any other better ways in general to share a variable between various functions.

Comment: Can you explain how this relates to "security"? What exactly do you want to "secure"?

Comment: `are there any other better ways in general to share a variable between various functions.` Yes, there are lots of other ways.  In virtually all cases you should be using a method's parameters to pass it data, not setting a static field.

Comment: @CodeCaster I want to know if keeping the value contained in the variable available in memory for a longer time than usual a concern.

Comment: The way you're setting that static field in the `otherreset` method doesn't really make sense either. You're creating an object, then using the instance of that object to modify the static variable. Skip the middle man by making `i` public, then you can modify it by writing `Program.i = value`.

Comment: @MageXy at certain situations, VS compains that I have to use an object reference for i even if I make it Public.

Comment: @Servy so even if I am forced to use a void function and I pass a variable as a parameter, then I assume, I should use "out" to get the changed value.

Comment: @JOW Why are you forced to use a void function?

Comment: @Servy sometimes I end up with an async void method when i'm working with asynchronous event handlers.

Comment: @JOW Then there is no need to return a value from such a method, because it's an event handler.  The type invoking the event isn't going to be expecting to get a value out of the method.

Comment: @Servy thanks. seems like i have to avoid async void methods too. http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static int i = 0; // A private static integer
```

Here you declared a static member. So far so good.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 1;// The main function is changing this integer
}
```

No, it doesn't. `int i` means you declared a *new* local variable named `i`.

```
void reset() { 
    int i = 0;// another function is changing the value of integer i
}
```

No, it doesn't. `int i` means you declared a *new* local variable named `i`.

> I'd like to know if this is a standard practice from a security perspective.

No, it isn't, and no, it's not related to security. You should *avoid* using static members as much as possible. I think that the actual reasons *why* are, currently, way too far from your current level of knowledge and understanding. Just take it as a best practice.

> I am concerned that the variable resides in the same location in memory throughout the execution of the program.

Well, a variable that would 'travel' between memory locations wouldn't be a good idea :-) Variables are, very simplistically put, named locations in memory.

> are there any other better ways in general to share a variable between various functions.

Yes, start by learning about function parameters, member fields, and properties. Use whatever beginner C# book you have available, or search online.

Comment: I've edited the code again to rid of the declaration, thanks for the answer

Comment: @downvoter is welcome to improve my answer and/or comment on how to make it more useful for the beginner OP.

Comment: @JOW Good, then just ignore the first part of my answer :-) You've already figured out it didn't do what you expected.