# Purpose of Static objects inside class

Tags: c#

```
    class A {
}
class B
{
static A a;
}
```

What does this mean? dose it mean i can have only instance of class A inside class B?

Comment: You should start your adventure with C# on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx

Comment: It means that all your instances of class `B` share the same reference to an instance of class `A`.

Comment: This kind of question is off-topic on stackoverflow where we try to fix concrete programming issues. You might get some help on fundamental language questions on _programmers_: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/163457/understanding-the-static-keyword

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the use of static variable in C#? When to use it? Why can't I declare the static variable inside method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795502/what-is-the-use-of-static-variable-in-c-when-to-use-it-why-cant-i-declare-th)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of instances of `A` within `B` is not determinded by `static` or any other keyword, but by the definition of the member `a` within class `B`. So when `a` is just **one** `A`, there surely is exactly *one* instance of `A` per `B`. However if `a` is declared as a list you surely have more instances.

`Static` simply means that your instances of `B` share the same reference to your instance of `A`, so with your code you have exactly one instance of `A` that can be used by any kind of `B`. Moreover you do not even need an instance of `B` to access that single instance of `A`. However it does not mean that only one instance of `A` exist within your application as other classes might create instances of `A` as well.