# How to implement the default constructor (using constructor chaining) that sets the Category to Miscellaneous

Tags: c#

I am very new to programming so I was trying to do some work with and got stuck with my problem.
Here is my code:

```
//Properties
private static readonly List<string> category = new List<string> 
{ 
    "Electric", 
    "Household", 
    "Garden", 
    "Miscellaneous" 
};
```

Category HAS to be "readonly"

```
// Constructor
public Product(List<string> category)
{
    // this.category shows error that it cannot be accessed with an instance reference; 
    // qualify it with a type name instead
    this.category = category;
}
```

Also in the default constructor I cannot pass it

```
// Default Constructor
public Product() : this("Miscellaneous")
{
}
```

So, how to pass 1 one of strings within the list? Or should I use arrays for this? And how do I print it out later?

```
class TestProduct
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Assigning correct properties to the product
        Product p1 = new Product(1234567, "Cake", "Miscellaneous", 7.5, 150);
        Console.WriteLine(p1);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Hope my question is clear.

Comment: Please focus on one question at a time, makes it much easier to write up good answers to it. It sounds to me as though you shouldn't use `static`, may I ask why you decided to make the list static but try to set it from an *instance* constructor?

Comment: Ok, I've sold my first problem by removing the "static" keyword. Kinda missed it out in my code. Still don't know how to do the other two.

Comment: This is an unfortunate effect of posting multiple questions together, not only do you risk getting multiple answers that only *together* answer everything, but when you start removing questions you risk also answers now no longer answering *anything*. Please avoid doing this. In other words, post 1 question and if it turns out to be a mistake, delete the question (the delete button). Don't edit out things people have already started answering.

Comment: This was my first question, so I'll try to make my questions more specific next time. Sorry for the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a fixed set of categories, you can use an `enum` to store all values.

```
public enum ProductCategory
{
    Electric,
    Household,
    Garden,
    Miscellaneous
}
```

You can create a default constructor like this:

```
public enum ProductCategory
{
    Electric,
    Household,
    Garden,
    Miscellaneous
}

public class Product
{

    public ProductCategory Category { get; }

    public Product(ProductCategory category)
    {
        this.Category = category;
    }

    public Product() : this(ProductCategory.Miscellaneous)
    {
    }

}

static void Main()
{
    Product p1 = new Product();
    Console.WriteLine(p1.Category); // output: Miscellaneous
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

If you still want to store your category in a string, you can adapt this example. If you want a fixed list of valid categories, you can check if the category is valid in the constructor.

Comment: Although I like all of the answers but this is an amazing way to store set amount of categories and works really well. Thank you.

Comment: So the "correct answer" was to not actually answer your question but instead show you a different way to do it? This answer does not answer the problems described in the question (qualify with type name, default constructor). but instead gives a (good, in all fairness) workaround?

Comment: As I said, should I use arrays instead of list, but I was given another option to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Category HAS to be "readonly"

The problem is not that it is readonly, the reason why you're getting `cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead` is because you declared the property as static. A [static property cannot be accessed as an instance property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664451(v=vs.71).aspx).

> Also in the default constructor I cannot pass it

Yes you can, if you actually pass in the type you declared.

```
public Product() : this("Miscellaneous") //You're trying to pass in a string
{
}
```

Can you see why you cannot pass in that string into your base constructor?

```
public Product(List<string> category) //base constructor takes a List<string>
{
    //stuff
}
```

You could create a base constructor which actually takes a string:

```
public Product(string cat)
{
    //Validate that the category passed in is valid, I.E. in your list
    foreach (var item in category)
    {
        if(object.Equals(item, cat))
            break;
        if(object.Equals(item, category.Last()))
            throw new Exception("D'oh! Invalid category");
    }

    //do stuff
}
```

Something like that. There are probably better ways to validate. Or just make your categories an Enum and use something like [Enum.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317(v=vs.110).aspx) to validate instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've solved the problem with Enum.

Comment: So the "correct answer" was to not actually answer your question but instead show you a different way to do it? This answer does not answer the problems described in the question (qualify with type name, default constructor). but instead gives a (good, in all fairness) workaround?

Comment: @Rufat - Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future reference. Because the question you asked is not the question that the accepted answer acutally gives an answer to.

Comment: Sorry, if that hurt you in some way, but I am new here, so I will try to improve on my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `this` qualifier from `this.category` because you are accessing a static variable which by definition cannot belong to an instance of a class.

Of course this means you'll get a naming collision because the static `category` cannot be differentiated from the local `category` - so fall back to using a naming convention like an underscore at the start of the name for the static variable - `_category`.

You should also rethink why you made the private variable `category` static - there is no reason for it to be that way.

> [...] that sets the Category to Miscellaneous

To solve your main issue - there is no way to do this without writing a new constructor that takes a single string (because you cannot statically define or enforce the length of a `List<>`, you can only check that programmatically). A good option is to use enums as [suggested by @apk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40303886/109702), then throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` from within the chained constructor if the value *Miscellaneous* isn't passed in. **But you should rethink even that strategy** - if the value **must** be *Miscellaneous* then consider defaulting to that in the chained constructor, don't allow an arbitrary value to be passed in and then test for the one possible correct value.

Comment: To be honest, given the scarcity of information from OP, an equally good answer would be to remove the `static` qualifier.

Comment: @decPL You are absolutely right, especially as the OP hasn't specified why they want it static.

Comment: He could also be using Product.category = category;

Comment: It is true that I forgot to remove static from there. I've solved that, and trying to work on other issues.

Comment: @Rufat I've addressed your main issue.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! My upvotes don't count though.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you don't actually want it to be a `static` variable ([this question might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795502/what-is-the-use-of-static-variable-in-c-when-to-use-it-why-cant-i-declare-th)), as long as you are receiving it in the constructor. Maybe what you want it is to be immutable, which is something quite different.

You can define that constructor this way.

```
public class Product
{
    private readonly List<string> _categories;

    public Product() : this(new List<string>() { "Miscellanous"})
    {

    }

    public Product(List<string> category)
    {
        _categories = category;
    }
}
```

Or this way

```
public class Product
{
    // other code
    public Product()
    {
         categories = new List<string>();
         categories.Add("Miscellanous");
    }
}
```

Also `readonly` only forbids changing the reference to the `_categories` variable. If you want the content to be immutable, then you [should have a look at other kind of data structures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467185(v=vs.111).aspx) or simply do it in the code.

Comment: The static part was indeed a mistake which was left from the previous attempt. Thanks a lot for your help and the article!