# Why AsyncLocal is different from CallContext

Tags: c#, multithreading, callcontext

Running the bellow code you can see that there is a different between CallContext and AsyncLocal.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Threading;

namespace AsyncLocalIsDifferentThanCallContext
{
    class Program
    {
        public static AsyncLocal<int> AsyncLocal = new AsyncLocal<int>();

        public static int CallContextValue
        {
            get
            {
                var data = CallContext.GetData("CallContextValue");
                if (data == null)
                    return 0;
                return (int) data;
            }
            set { CallContext.SetData("CallContextValue", value); }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AsyncLocal.Value = 1;
            CallContextValue = 1;
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("From thread AsyncLocal: " + AsyncLocal.Value); // Should be 0 but is 1
                Console.WriteLine("From thread CallContext: " + CallContextValue); // Value is 0, as it should be
            }).Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Main AsyncLocal: " + AsyncLocal.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("Main CallContext: " + CallContextValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you explain why?

I expected the value of AsyncLocal to be unique per thread as the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906268(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5) says it should behave and as CallContext behaves.

Comment: Why would you expect different values? The object you are using is static so just 1 instance can exist of this object. You set the value of this object to a specific value. And then get and print this value, the only thing is you do the very same thing in different threads. I think your expectance is disturbed by using static variables. Read up on static variables here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795502/what-is-the-use-of-static-variable-in-c-when-to-use-it-why-cant-i-declare-th

Comment: My understanding that AsyncLocal should replace CallContext on .net core (as there is no CallContext there) and it should hold a value unique to the thread. Also see the link to the documentation.

Comment: There's no task in your example, which is thread based. `AsyncLocal` isn't relevant to anything you are doing here.

Comment: Use LogicalGet/SetData() instead.  Although it isn't exactly clear what the point might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You thinking of `ThreadLocal`? `AsyncLocal` can flow across threads as it says

> Because the task-based asynchronous programming model tends to abstract the use of threads, AsyncLocal instances can be used to **persist data across threads**.