# How to instanciate an object and use this object throughout the program?

Tags: c#, variables, scope

Here is my problem,

I fetch a json from a webservice and deserialize it into an object. Now, I want this object and its values to be accessible from anywhere in the program, how can I do that ? PS: the ultimate goal being the possibility to access the user id of this object from another class.

```
HttpClientService clientActeur = new HttpClientService();

ActeurJson acteurJson = new ActeurJson();
acteurJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ActeurJson>(await clientActeur.loadActeur(Login,Pass));
```

Here are the **actorJson** Class and the **Actor** class

```
    public class ActeurJson
        {
            [JsonProperty("Acteur")]
            public Acteur Acteur { get; set; }
        }

public class Acteur
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("nom")]
        public string nom { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("prenom")]
        public string prenom { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("login")]
        public string login { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("mdp")]
        public string mdp { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("adresse")]
        public string adresse { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("cp")]
        public string cp { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("ville")]
        public string ville { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("dateEmbauche")]
        public string dateEmbauche { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("idTypeActeur")]
        public string idTypeActeur { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("oldMdp")]
        public string oldMdp { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("mail")]
        public string mail { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("questionSecrete")]
        public string questionSecrete { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("version")]
        public string version { get; set; }
    }
```

I already tried using the static keyword before the public class, it is not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the use of static variable in C#? When to use it? Why can't I declare the static variable inside method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795502/what-is-the-use-of-static-variable-in-c-when-to-use-it-why-cant-i-declare-th)

Comment: so by that you mean I should put the fields as static and not the entire class ?

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make the ActeurJson.Acteur property static. If you are going to do it your two best options are :

making it a static class

```
 public static class ActeurJson {
     [JsonProperty("Acteur")]
     public static Acteur Acteur { get; set; }
 }
```

You can make it static property of the Acteur or ActeurJson class.

```
public class Acteur {
    [JsonProperty("Acteur")]
    public static Acteur ActeurJson { get; set; }


    /* the rest of your class code. */
}
```

Comment: when using the static keyword I'm met with: cannot declare instance members in a static class , which is why I said using the static word on the entire class did not work

Comment: There's no such thing as a global variable in C#.

Comment: @itsme86 Yeah, that was a mistake, I fixed my wording