# Accessing static properties within non-static classes within parallel test runs

Tags: c#, selenium, parallel-processing

I know if I have a static class with static properties, then that state will be shared with all threads that are running.

1) But lets say I have a non static class with a static property will that static property (which changes per login, i.e. session_token) be shared across all threads?

If it is shared, then things like session variables cannot be stored in a static property.

2) How would one do this?

Comment: My first intuition: the static properties should not differ depending on static/not static class (Note: i'm not sure, it just a (n educated) guess). However, storing session data in some static value doesn't seem that good of an idea. You could store it in a static property, but I would suggest then using a static class that has some form of dictionary behaviour to retrieve only specific requested items, and not just entire user data without proper indication

Comment: A static anything is shared, no matter if it's in a static class or not. Take a look at ThreadLocal<T> if you need something per thread, but I dont think you're going to be able to  use that with session related things. ASP is a different beast when it comes to using shared state

Comment: @H.J.Meijer even if i used a dictionary the threads will be overwriting each key.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Yeah atm I've got like 20 static strings with the attribute `[ThreadStatic]` but I don't think this is an elegant way to do it.

Comment: ThreadStatic attribute is different from the ThreadLocal class. The attribute only applies to fields I believe; it will also only initialize the values once (for the first thread) and the rest is up to you. ThreadLocal is my preference.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 do you have any examples on how you would use it?

Answer (score 0):

**1)**

Static variables are shared across all instances of the class, whether or not the class is static.

A better explanation can be found at this question:

[What is the use of static variable in C#? When to use it? Why can't I declare the static variable inside method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795502/what-is-the-use-of-static-variable-in-c-when-to-use-it-why-cant-i-declare-th)

**2)**

Session variables can be stored in statics. Just because they are global do not mean they are immutable, simply change the static property when the session ID changes.

Comment: Lets say i have `static string session_token`, when I have one thread running then this is fine. When I have >1 thread(T) writing to `session_token` then T2 overwrites T2 and they both will use T2 and my tests are screwed.

Comment: In this case I wouldn't use a static, because the point of a static is that it is global for all. You could try having an initial session ID static, and then a new non static for any instances after the first one.