# How to only make this attribute change on the current browser session not all sessions?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

This is the testing class:

```
    namespace ScopedTest.Data
{
    public class TestingClass
    {
        public static string? Name { get; set; } = "HAHA";
    }
}
```

and here is the class im working with:

```
@using ScopedTest.Data
@inject TestingClass Name

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<input type="text" @bind-value=@Name />

<p> @Name </p>
```

When I open this webpage on 2 different browsers (chrome and firefox for exmaple) when I change the name in Chrome and then refresh on Firefox the name gets updated on firefox as well and I do not why or how it is doing this, the purpose of this test is to try and only keep the data on the browser without it changing when hitting refresh. any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795502/

Comment: How do you add `TestingClass` to the dependency injection container?

Comment: You could use the browsers session storage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your service with 'scoped' lifetime.

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<TestingClass>();
```

For Singleton services you get the same instance for all sessions.

For Scoped services you get a different instance per session.

https://chrissainty.com/service-lifetimes-in-blazor/

Comment: I did but It kept giving me this error "InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'Name' on type 'ScopedTest.Pages.Counter'. There is no registered service of type 'ScopedTest.Data.TestingClass'.'

Comment: Can you share your `Program.cs` code?